# Rails 4: Manipulate column on retrieval

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am looking for a way to implement a callback, triggered each time a record is retrieved, that formats a column on that record.

For example, storing percentages in the database without a decimal point. 10% is stored as 10, but I want to reliably be able to treat is as .1 in my calculations with it, so I need to change it on retrieval. How would I do that?

Pseudo-code might look like this:

numbers.rb

```
class Numbers < ActiveRecord::Base

    after_retrieval :return_percentage_to_decimal

    def return_percentage_to_decimal
        return percentage / 100
    end

end
```

This means when I call @number.percentage, it returns .1, not 10. This would eliminate the possibility of my forgetting to call @number.percentage.return_percentage_to_decimal every time I use it in a calculation.

Or perhaps the information is hard to find because there are reasons I shouldn't be doing this...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just define the method (like u did) and forget that callback thing ;) you don't need any callback, your method is evaluated when called and returns what you want

Comment: @Marian, I'm looking to never call that data in it's stored format. I would like number.percent to return .1, not 10. I'm also looking to not have to call number.percent.return_percentage_to_decimal.

Comment: Added that language to my question to clarify what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the `percentage` and `percentage=` methods in your model. You need to override the setter as well so your data round-trips without changes.

```
CONVERSION_FACTOR = 100.0    

def percentage
  super / CONVERSION_FACTOR
end

def percentage= new_val
  super(new_val * CONVERSION_FACTOR)
end
```